# Solving an equation in field $\mathbb Z_{11}$ using GAP

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, math-software, gap

Here is a solved [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/464750/8581). I want for myself to examine it with GAP. So I did the following:

```
 > t:=Field( Z(11) );;
 > s:=Elements(t);

 [ 0*Z(11), Z(11)^0, Z(11), Z(11)^2, Z(11)^3, Z(11)^4, Z(11)^5, Z(11)^6, 
   Z(11)^7, Z(11)^8, Z(11)^9 ]

 > for alpha in s do
     if alpha^(12)-alpha^(10)= s[3] then Print(alpha,"\n");
     fi;
   od;
```

The final answers are:

```
   Z(11)^4,  Z(11)^9
```

Is this attempt acceptable from your point of view? Any other suggestions will be appreciated. (-:

Comment: I understand almost nothing of what you did above, but $$x^{12}-x^{10}=2\implies x^2=3\implies x_{1,2}=5,6\pmod{11}$$ since clearly zero is not a solution and $\,x^{10}=1\pmod{11}\;$ for every nonzero $\,x\,$. I don't know if this helps...

Comment: @DonAntonio: I know that. I just wanted to make a model for my self by using codes. I posted this here to find out is it a final proper codes or not. The problem has solved and I don't want to do for it anymore. Thanks.

Comment: How does GAP store elements of a finite field? For the answer to make sense to me I'm guessing that it probably represents them as powers of the primitive root $2$. Can anyone confirm/refute this?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: yes, `Int(Z(11))` returns `2`.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thanks for your consideration to this question. Thanks Jack. ;)

Comment: @BabakS. By this question, I learn a lot about GAP +1;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find a list of roots of a univariate polynomial, use `RootsOfUPol` (see `?RootsOfUPol` in GAP for the documentation):

```
gap> x:=Indeterminate(GF(11),"x");
x
gap> f:=x^12-x^10-Z(11);
x^12-x^10+Z(11)^6
gap> RootsOfUPol(f);
[ Z(11)^9, Z(11)^4 ]
```

Note that these two are precisely 6 and 5 modulo 11, respectively:

```
gap> List(last,Int);
[ 6, 5 ]
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander but what about @Jyrki's comment? It seems correct.

Comment: @BabaK: Jack Schmidt already confirmed that: $2^9\equiv 6\pmod{11}$ and $2^4\equiv 5\pmod{11}$, so it checks out as I expected. My (+1) to Alexander has been there from the beginning.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: thanks! Just to add that there is a difference between asking how GAP stores and how represents (in its output) FFEs (finite field elements). The answer depends on the order of the field, see `?Z (for field size)` for more details and then also scroll till the end of the displayed chapter for "Printing, Viewing and Displaying Finite Field Elements".